# Elasticsearch query to return the most recent of 'each document' based on a condition

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to retrieve the most recent version of each document in my dataset when the document is not already archived (`archived: false`). So when any version of the document has archived set to true, it should not appear in my result.

An example of my dataset:

```
 {
    name: "soccer game",
    base_id: 1,
    hours_remaining: 10,
    updatedDate: 2019 - 03 - 10,
    archived: false
}

{
    name: 'basketball game",
    base_id: 2,
    hours_remaining: 20,
    updatedDate: 2019 - 03 - 10,
    archived: false
}

{
    name: "soccer game",
    base_id: 1,
    hours_remaining: 5,
    updatedDate: 2019 - 03 - 14,
    archived: true
}
```

The expected result is :

```
{
    name: 'basketball game",
    base_id: 2,
    hours_remaining: 20,
    timestamp: 2019 - 03 - 10,
    archived: false
}
```

After writing several queries, I haven't been able to achieve my goal. This is one of my attempts.

```
{
  "size": 10, 
   "query":{
     "bool":{
       "must":[
         {
           "query_string":{
             "query": "*",
             "fields":["name.keyword"]
           }
         },
         {
           "term":{
             "archived": false
           }
          }
       ]
     }
   },
   "collapse": {
    "field": "base_id",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "most_recent",
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [{"updatedDate": "desc"}]
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `query_string` can be avoided. If you would like to get only the `archived: false`, the name is not necessary.

I think you should first use a `must` condition to filter the ones that have the field archived set to False, then you should use a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `name` field so it will bring you back the unique names that fulfill the `must` condition.

You can then use a [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) as sub-aggregation to bring you only the biggest value in the `updatedDate` field. The final query should look like this:

```
"size": 0, #We don't care about the size of this
"query":{
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "term":{
        "archieved": false #Only false will be shown
      }
    }
  },
}
"aggs":{
  "names":{
    "terms":{
      "field": "name.keyword" #Unique names will be shown here
    },
    "aggs":{
      "most_recent":{
        "max": {
          "field": "updatedDate" #The max value of this field
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: It didn't work for me. Several versions of the same document appear multiple times in the result.

Comment: I think I forgot to add the "query" field in my suggestion. Could you please share the results you got?

Comment: I would use top_hits in order to retrieve the last document inside the aggregation:
"aggs":{ "names":{
    "terms":{
      "field": "name.keyword" #Unique names will be shown here
    },
     "aggs": {
       "last_update_top_hirs": {
           "top_hits": {
             "sort": [
                {
                   "updatedDate": {
                       "order": "desc"
                    }
                 }
               ],
               "size" : 1
            }
        }
      }
 }
}

Comment: Top hits will do match_all with the documents inside the bucket, making it appear more than once. But yes, ordering its results 'desc' is a good alternative. If you feel comfortable with your query, you can post it as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: @LeBigCat I've used top_hits and it didn't work. The response includes the last version of a document when archived was `false`.

Comment: You have still to filter (= put the query part). You confirm your exemple in not an array of a nested documents right?

Comment: My example is not an array of a nested documents. I did also add the query.

Comment: I just read back the topic. You dont expect  name: "soccer game" in your result too (= you dont want the last archived = false of each name )?

Comment: Yes, you understand my question now.

Answer (score -1):

This is more simple. Query on archived, regardless of anything else.
then order by date desc, and keep only the first one (size = 1)

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "archived": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "updatedDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```